# Can a data type be defined which stores a lambda function that has the same data type as parameter?

Tags: lambda, isabelle

I'm trying to create a data type which contains a lambda function which takes the same data type as argument.

Here is an example:

```
datatype id = n_1 | n_2

type_synonym entry = "(id * (entry list ⇒ nat))"
type_synonym myList = "entry list"

fun ivalue :: "myList ⇒ nat"
  where
    "ivalue [] = 0" |
    "ivalue (x # xs) = snd x (x xs)"

fun search :: "myList ⇒ id ⇒ myList"
  where
    "search [] t = []" |
    "search (x # xs) t = (if fst x = t then (x # xs) else search xs t)"

definition my_list :: "myList"
  where
    "my_list = [(n_1, %p.(42::nat)),
                (n_2, %p.(ivalue (search p n_1)) + 6)]"
```

The idea of the code is to have list of tuples with an ID and an expression. The expression is realized by a lambda function which can get a list of the same format itself. The `search` and `ivalue` functions allow to refer to other entries in the expression. The expected result of an algorithm which evaluates all expressions in `my_list` would be `[(n_1, 42), (n_2, 48)]`.

The definition of `entry` is obviously wrong, but hopefully makes it clear what I try to achieve. Is there a way to create such a data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because it would be mathematically inconsistent. Simply put, such a datatype would be too large to fit into a set. (If it did, one could easily construct an injection from the power set of this type into itself)

You can find a more detailed explanation e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921002/isabelle-unsupported-recursive-occurrence-of-a-datatype-via-type-constructor-s).

If the functions you want to store have a restricted domain (e.g. finite or countable), it might be possible to get this to work. I would have naively thought that a finite map would work:

```
datatype entry = Entry id "(entry list, nat) fmap"
```

But apparently it doesn't. Whether that's due to a deep logical issue or simply because `fmap` wasn't set up properly to support this, I'm not sure. I suspect it is the latter though, since the following similar thing does work:

```
datatype entry = Entry id "(entry list × nat) fset"
```

Would a finite map be sufficient for you?

Comment: I think a simple mapping of an entry list to a number is not sufficient for my purpose. The core idea is to use lambda functions to represent simple mathematical expressions that can refer to other expressions in the list.

Comment: Yeah, if it really has to be a proper function without any restrictions on the domain, that cannot possibly work because that datatype simply wouldn't fit into a set. You could maybe try something like a deep embedding of these expressions